# Getting from San Diego airport to near the Convention Centre without a car?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, southern-california, san-diego

For an upcoming trip, I'll be arriving into San Diego airport (international terminal if that matters) early evening. Hotel isn't confirmed yet, but it's looking very likely to be somewhere close to the convention centre, so just south of the Gaslight Quarter. What I won't have is a car!

Is there any sensible public transport options to get you from the airport down to the Convention Centre or the Gaslight Quarter? Or are there any private airport transfer buses that people have found good in the past?

Or should I just give in and pay for a taxi for the ~5 mile trip?

Comment: I think you mean "Gaslamp". (Disclaimer: I'm a San Diego resident.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of airport shuttle companies that handle transportation to and from the airport. They cost around $15 per person.

Metro bus #992 The Flyer ($2.25) travels 10 minutes to the Santa Fe Depot in downtown San Diego, where you can connect to the Coaster commuter train, the Trolley, and Amtrak to get you anywhere else.

[Source](http://wikitravel.org/en/San_Diego#Get_in)

Comment: Looks like the [last #992 bus](http://developer.sdmts.com/sdmtsapp/mtscr/TimeTable.aspx?r=992&d=Counterclockwise&display=V&tod=wd) is about 11pm, so I should be fine! They look to be about every 15 minutes, so that seems a cheap and simple way to do it :)

Comment: From Santa Fe Depot the easiest way to the Convention Center is to take the trolley, two stops south on the Green Line.  There are no free transfers from the Metro bus, but you can buy a day pass (valid on bus and trolley) instead of the regular bus fare for $5.  Or you can walk 1.1 km from Santa Fe Depot.